# Benford Distribution

Tags: python

Hello I am trying to write a code for Benford distribution, but I got this errror:

```
def leading_digit(n):
    while n >= 10:
        n = n//10
    return n

def Ben(k):
    results = []
    for i in range(k):
        random_number[i] = np.random.randint(10000)
        results.append(leading_digit(random_number[i]))
    return results

Ben(2)
```

Error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-5811e9105b42> in <module>
----> 1 Ben(2)

<ipython-input-26-5df31a0e6a56> in Ben(k)
      2     results = []
      3     for i in range(k):
----> 4         random_number[i] = np.random.randint(10000)
      5         results.append(leading_digit(random_number[i]))
      6     return results

NameError: name 'random_number' is not defined
```

Comment: Shouldn't you need to initialize the `random_number` list somewhere in the `Ben` function or in the global scope?

Comment: What do/don’t you understand from that error message?

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize `random_number` list (`random_number = [0] * k`) with some value since it reports the variable `random_number` not defined error.

```
def leading_digit(n):
    while n >= 10:
        n = n//10
    return n

def Ben(k):
    results = []
    random_number = [0] * k
    for i in range(k):
        random_number[i] = np.random.randint(10000)
        results.append(leading_digit(random_number[i]))
    return results

Ben(2)
```